# Filter cell by row in dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe with project information including a column with staff and roles. I'm trying to filter the staff according to their role.

The data look like:

```
project, staff  
project1, 'jane (role1), john (role2), bob (role3)'  
project2, 'sue (role2), bob (role3)'  
project3, 'mike (role1), claire (role3)'
```

I'm trying to filter out names by role, but can't get it to work. So, for example, if I want only role 2, the output would be:

```
project, staff  
project1, john  
project2, sue  
project3, NA
```

I've tried variations on

```
str_subset(str_split(df$staff,","),"role2")
```

and

```
grep('role2',str_split(df$staff`,","),value=TRUE)
```

but it doesn't work.

If no one on the team is in role 2, I get an empty list (that's good). If someone on the team is in role 2, I get a list of all team members (not good). There appears to be an issue with the order of operations - it's checking the string for role2, then splitting. I don't understand why.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. There might be a cleaner way but this will get you what you want.

```
df <- read.table(text= "project1, 'jane (role1), john (role2), bob (role3)'
project2, 'sue (role2), bob (role3)'
           project3, 'mike (role1), claire (role3)'", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

temp <- strsplit(df$V2, ',', fixed = T)
temp <- sapply(temp, function(x){
  x[grep('role2', x)]
})
ndf <- data.frame(cbind(df$V1, temp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (see comments in code for explanation):

```
df <- data.frame(project = c("project1","project2","project3"),
                 staff = c('jane (role1), john (role2), bob (role3)','sue (role2), bob (role3)','mike (role1), claire (role3)'))    

# 1st we split the concatenated field and cbind it to the project, then rbind it all
df2 <- setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,apply(df,1,function(row){cbind(row[1],strsplit(row[2],", ")[[1]])}))),c("project","staff")) 
# then we separate name and role
df2$role <- gsub(".*\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", df2[,2])
df2$name <- gsub(" \\((.*)\\)", "", df2[,2])
# then we subset what we need
subset(df2,role=="role2")
# project        staff  role name
# 2 project1 john (role2) role2 john
# 4 project2  sue (role2) role2  sue
```